# how to install the same app twice?

Tags: android, google-play, android-productflavors

To install two different instances of the same app is easy. I just use productFlavors.

The problem comes when I install the app from Google Play and try to install another flavor. I can't have an app from Google Play and a flavor one at the same time but two flavors apps yes.

How can I install both apps in the same phone, Google Play app and Flavor app.

PD: I am using different flavors, this is an example of them:

```
     QA {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "My app QA"
            applicationId "com.myapp.qa"
        }

        GOOGLEPLAY{
             resValue "string", "app_name", "My app GOOGLE PLAY"
            applicationId "com.myapp.release"
        }

        TESTING {
             resValue "string", "app_name", "My app TEST"
            applicationId "com.myapp.test"
        }

        DEVELOPMENT {
             resValue "string", "app_name", "My app DEV"
            applicationId "com.myapp.dev"
        }
```

Comment: Use `applicationIdSuffix` on the `debug` `buildType`: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id#change_the_application_id_for_build_variants

Answer (score 0):

Define Flavors

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    }
    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationIdSuffix ".free"
        }
        pro {
            applicationIdSuffix ".pro"
        }
    }
}
```

The key is the applicactionIdSuffix

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
}
```